# navigation.xml : activities missing, preview and linking unavailable

Tags: android, navigation

I've just learned about the whole navigation feature in Android, how you can draw a graph and link fragments or activities in order to visualize the flow and pass intents parameters safely through a navigation.xml file.

I have 3 different issues right from the start :

1. Not all activities can be added to the graph through the editor (I'm aware I can write the XML in the text tab but I believe there's some kind of issue)
2. All previews are missing (not a big deal again but still intriguing)
3. I cannot link the activities

Do you have any clues of what could've caused this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Not all activities can be added to the graph through the editor (I'm aware I can write the XML in the text tab but I believe there's some kind of issue)

You should [file a bug against the Navigation Editor](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=404706) if you're able to reproduce this in a sample project using the latest Android Studio as all activities should be listed. Note that activities you've already added to your graph are filtered out from the Add Destination list (as you've already added it).

> 2. All previews are missing (not a big deal again but still intriguing)

The Navigation Editor relies on some layout in your project having a `tools:context` pointing to your activity (i.e., `tools:context="com.example.MainActivity"`) to automatically populate a layout. This check is only done when first adding the destination to your graph - after the fact, you'd need to add a `tools:layout="@layout/main_activity"` attribute to your destination manually.

> 3. I cannot link the activities

As per the [Getting Started guide for Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#add-navhost):

> Note: The Navigation component is designed for apps that have one main activity with multiple fragment destinations. The main activity is associated with a navigation graph and contains a NavHostFragment that is responsible for swapping destinations as needed. **In an app with multiple activity destinations, each activity has its own navigation graph.**

In Navigation, an `<activity>` destination serves as an exit point - linking the graph of one activity to another activity, which would have its own navigation graph. The Navigation Editor prevents you from creating actions (the lines between destinations) from `<activity>` destinations because they can never be triggered - by starting an `<activity>` destination, you've left the old activity (and its graph) behind.

As per the [Migrate to the Navigation component documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-migrate), you should focus on converting one activity at a time to Navigation by building out the graph for just that activity (whether it contains just a single screen or multiple Fragments). `<activity>` destinations then allow you to link the separate activities together, replacing calls to `startActivity()` in a way that would allow you to seamlessly combine activities together if you so choose.

Answer (score 0):

If each of your activity holds multiple fragments, then what you can do is create a separate navigation graph for these activities. You can link the fragment in one activity to another activity in the navigation graph. So when the other activity will be called, the navigation graph for that activity can be used.