# How do I manually update the missing previews in the nav_graph in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-jetpack-navigation

After adding my fragments to my nav graph using the Navigation Component in Jetpack, I noticed I was missing some previews on the Nav Graph view. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56388420/navigation-xml-activities-missing-preview-and-linking-unavailable) answer from Ian Lake that was really helpful but wanted to clarify what he says in point 2 as it might be helpful to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to the XML view for the nav graph (ie use the Code or Split view). Click on a fragment that is missing its preview and in the XML add the tools:layout entry specifying the layout id, eg

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/myFragment"
        android:name="....MyFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/my_fragment_layout">
....
</fragment>
```